# Why doesn't the system() function work?

Tags: c, cmd, system

As I Know , in cmd , when we want to switch drives we write "[drive]:" exemple :
when we want to switch to D:\ we type

`D:`

and i try this and it work .

But now , I want to apply this process in my C program , so I used the famous "system " command and i type :

`system("D:");`

and i have some code after that , when i try to execute it , it write

```
the specified path was not found.
```

so i tried to see if the system comand really work and i add another system comand like this :

```
system("chdir");
```

to verify the working directory and when I execute it , it show me the path of the executable that's mean that the `system("D:");` dont work.

any solution please

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Why did you decide to use `system`?

Comment: I try to modify some files , and I want to go to the directory interactively. If there is an alternative tell me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably because `system()` starts a new instance of `cmd.exe`, which runs your command and then exits. Thus, it doesn't hold state between invocations, unlike when you run a single instance and give it multiple commands interactively.

One way of working around this is hinted at by `cmd.exe`'s help text:

> Note that multiple commands separated by the command separator `'&&'`
>   are accepted for string if surrounded by quotes.

So, you should be able to run a command like `"d: && chdir"` to do both operations in a single invocation of `cmd.exe`.